# Is it possible to have HTML in a visual force email template?

Tags: email, email-template, html

I have created a VisualForce template.  I need to use its advanced wiring facilities so can't use other template types.

I am trying to have some HTML in this template but not having much luck.

I add:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<I>This should be in italic</I>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

to the template but it comes out verbatim as:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<I>This should be in italic</I>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any ideas how I can add HTML to a visual force template?

Comment: Have you pasted it to `<messaging:htmlEmailBody >` or `<messaging:plainTextEmailBody>`?

Comment: You just beat me to it. Yes that works.  If you want to put that in as an answer, I'll accept it and delete my own.

Comment: That's fine, accept your own answer ;) I'm not THAT greedy for the rep. points and after all it means you did your own research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Sample Disbursement Receipt" recipientType="User"  relatedToType="Call__c">
 <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
 <html>
<body>
Please find your sample drop receipt attached with this mail.
    </body>
    </html>
   </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
   </messaging:emailTemplate>
```

The sample Template that you can use .